# Bitboard chess programming in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, chess

I have a problem with this piece of code in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint64_t bboard;

// Accessing a square of the bitboard
int
get (bboard b, int square)
{
  return (b & (1ULL << square));
}

void
print_board (bboard b)
{
  int i, j, square;
  for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) // rank => top to bottom
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) // file => left to right
        printf ("%d ", get (b, j+8*i) ? 1 : 0);
      printf ("\n");
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  bboard b = 0xffffffffffffffff;
  print_board (b);
}

// result that I have
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Ok, why the bitboard is not set with all bit at 1?

For any question please add a comment. Ty :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get` returns an `int`, but `(b & (1ULL << square))` is a `uint64_t`. When `(b & (1ULL << square))` is greater than `INT_MAX`, the result is undefined; in this case it truncates and returns `0`.

If `get` returns a `bboard` instead, this works as expected (verified here: http://codepad.org/zEZiJKeR).

Comment: You are not right, an overflow for signed types causes undefined
behavior, no truncation or wraparound is guaranteed